# Is it feasible to write a Firefox plugin to make use of ActiveX control on Windows?

Tags: firefox, plugins, activex

I use an ActiveX control called TAPIEx enabling TAPI phone system integration using MS Access 2000 (+Visual Basic). I want to turn this Access database into a web app with the clients running Firefox (all on internal network).

Since Firefox doesnt support ActiveX is it feasible for me to write a Firefox plugin that in turn utilizes the ActiveX control?

With regard to how plugins work - Would I be able to call 'functions' of the plugin from page script (eg dial call specifying phone number, check if calls in process)? Would adding these functions to the Firefox right click menu 'globally' inside Firefox be easier?

Hope you guys can help.  Note I'm not a fulltime programmer; I just need to know how steep the learning curve will be or even if my idea is possible!

#### Ive now found a project to allow using activex controls in firefox that seems to be quite up to date at:

#### http://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/

Comment: You know, you could just use IE and save all the hassle.

Comment: The problem with IE is that we are running windows 2000 on many systems and as such are limited v6.1 sp2 - were getting weird crashes that ive put down to this version so i want to move away from it. Is a visual basic firefox plugin not a reasonably manageable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, yes you could write a Firefox plugin with C++ that talked to the ActiveX component via COM. But the learning curve for both COM and C++ FF plugins are both horribly steep. I wouldn't recommend it.

As Kalmi says, just use IE.

Comment: The problem with IE is that we are running windows 2000 on many systems and as such are limited v6.1 sp2 - were getting weird crashes that ive put down to this version so i want to move away from it. Is a visual basic firefox plugin not a reasonably manageable solution?

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't possible to program a firefox extension in Visual Basic.

Comment: Thanks Matthew you've answered my question, this isn't the best direction to take the project right now.